# OpenLayers: How can I add multiple KML files to the same vector layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I'm trying to add some KML files to a vector layer using this code:

```
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');   
            map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
            var kml = ['kml/file1.kml','kml/file2.kml' ... 'kml/fileN.kml'];

            function createFeatures() {
                var features = [];
                for (var i=0; i<kml.length; i++) {
                        features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                            new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                                url: 'kml/file'+i+'.kml',
                                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML()
                            }
                        )));
                }
                return features;
            }

            var vectors1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer 1", {
                isBaseLayer: false,
                style: { strokeWidth: 3, strokeColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: 0.50, fillColor: "#FF0000" }
            });
            map.addLayer(vectors1); 
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            vectors1.addFeatures(createFeatures());
```

I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: a.geometry.getBounds is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector` creates a single feature from a geometry, which explains the error.  You would need to load each kml, which would be an asynchronous operation, and when loaded read the features and add them to the layer.  Here's some very basic code:

```
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');   
        map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
        var kml = ['kml/file1.kml','kml/file2.kml' ... 'kml/fileN.kml'];

        var vectors1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer 1", {
            isBaseLayer: false,
            style: { strokeWidth: 3, strokeColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: 0.50, fillColor: "#FF0000" }
        });
        map.addLayer(vectors1); 
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

        var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
            internalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913')
        });

        function loadKML(url) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var features = format.read(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(features);
                vectors1.addFeatures(features);
            }
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.send();
        }

        for (var i=0; i<kml.length; i++) {
            loadKML(kml[i]);
        }
```

Comment: With this I get no errors, but my KML files are not shown on the map.

Comment: Use console.log to check that features are being added, also zoom in on lat/lon 0,0 off the coast of Africa to see if they are there but in the wrong projection.

Comment: You are right, they are at Africa. But how? Before I tried to add them to the same layer, I created separate layers for each files, and they were displayed at the correct place.

Comment: The projections needed to be specified.  Hopefully adding then to the format will be sufficient.